# How to edit html in WpBakery(Visual Composer) page

Tags: wordpress

firstly I'm sorry for my english level.

There is a wordpress page that created with Visual Composer extension. Images in this page is not contain width height value. I want to add width height values to images in the page using html but I can't find html codes in page created with visual composer.

Please help me Why do I add to width and height values to this page.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there has an *Image size* input where you can specify width and height of image.

There a example from [WP Bakery Docs](https://kb.wpbakery.com/docs/wpbakery-page-builder-how-tos/how-to-add-and-edit-images/) video:

[image: Image size]

Comment: Unfortunately I have no area. My extension is old version and not premium.